# Percentage widths on input not working

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this is a basic question but here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/s7wdkxun/

I can't understand why this isn't working with the percentage widths, instead it stays as fixed pixels.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <input class="1">
    <input class="2">
    <input class="3">
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.1 {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%
}
.2 {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%
}
.3 {
    width: 20%
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If using unique classes, why not use ID's. And nor ID neither class can't start with digit.

Answer (score 4):

CSS classes cannot start with a number, per W3 spec.   Change it's name and it should work.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html

Answer (score 2):

**not have to do with numbers**
*Do NOT start an SELECTOR with a number!*

use:

```
<input class="one">
<input class="two">
<input class="tree">
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained here [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors):

> ...a name must begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or
>   a letter(a–z), followed by any number of hyphens, underscores,
>   letters, or numbers. There is a catch: if the first character is a
>   hyphen, the second character must be a letter or underscore, and the
>   name must be at least 2 characters long.

So if you update your class names to meet this criteria, for example change to `one`, `two`, and `three` it will work properly.  **[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Loaz7gcu/)**

Answer (score 1):

you can't have a class name that starts with a number... try input1 instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

You can't use classes that starts with digits. Try to give them string names

Answer (score 0):

I also faced for this issue, reason for that I have put input tag inside the lable,
solution : remove label

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35380144)